# Carrierwave is not displaying file path in xml view - Is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I've got an app that works with Carrierwave. I can even do something like @product.image.url which will give me the path to url of the stored image.

However, when I browse to products#show (i.e. http://localhost:3000/products/1.xml), it displays everything correctly except for the image.

In the console, @product.image.url, returns:

```
"https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/products/2/prod1.jpg"
```

The image only displays the name and the extension. Not the path. Is this normal?

For example, the xml looks like:

```
product>
  <attachment>prod1.jpg</attachment>
  <cached-slug>adsfsadf</cached-slug>
  <category-id type="integer">1</category-id>
  <company-id type="integer">1</company-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2011-05-10T05:10:35Z</created-at>
  <description>description here</description>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I think Carrierwave is generating the url dynamically (within a method), so you can change or override the way its computed.

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @product.to_xml(:include => {:attachment => {:only => :url}}) }
```

EDIT : 
Works for me :

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @product.to_xml(:except => :attachment, :methods => :attachment_url) }
```

Comment: I get undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass